# How do I extend a list from a parent class?

Tags: python, list, inheritance, superclass

I have the following code. The parent class has a list of items, which the children need to add to.

Every instance of parent needs to have this list, and every child needs to have that list + the extra values.

```
class Parent(object):
    a_list = ['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', ]

    def print_list(self):
        print(self.a_list)


class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Child1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a_list += ['child1_item']


class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Child2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a_list += ['child2_item']


parent = Parent()
child1 = Child1()
child2 = Child2()

parent.print_list()
    # >> ['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', 'child1_item', 'child2_item']
child1.print_list()
    # >> ['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', 'child1_item', 'child2_item']
child2.print_list()
    # >> ['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', 'child1_item', 'child2_item']
```

How can I get the following result instead?

```
['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', ]
['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', 'child1_item', ]
['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', 'child2_item', ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list += other_list` extend the list **in-place**. Use `+` operator which returns a new list:

```
class Parent(object):
    a_list = ['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', ]
    def print_list(self):
        print(self.a_list)

class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Child1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a_list = self.a_list + ['child1_item']  # <-------

class Child2(Parent):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Child2, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.a_list = self.a_list + ['child2_item']  # <-------


parent = Parent()
child1 = Child1()
child2 = Child2()
parent.print_list()
child1.print_list()
child2.print_list()
```

output:

```
['parent_item1', 'parent_item2']
['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', 'child1_item']
['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', 'child2_item']
```

---

Alternatively, you can make a copy of the parent class' list:

```
...
self.a_list = self.a_list[:]
self.a_list += ['child1_item']
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a constructor for `Parent`. The problem is that they are all sharing the same list that gets created when `Parent` gets declared. Instead, you want:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_list = ['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', ]
    def print_list(self):
        print(self.a_list)
```

That way, whenever you construct a Parent, you create a brand new list containing `['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', ]`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the solution was very simple and clean. There is no need for super, or init()

```
class Parent(object):
    a_list = ['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', ]

    def print_list(self):
        print(self.a_list)


class Child1(Parent):
    a_list = Parent.a_list + ['child1_item', ]


class Child2(Parent):
    a_list = Parent.a_list + ['child2_item', ]


parent = Parent()
child1 = Child1()
child2 = Child2()

parent.print_list()
    # >> ['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', ]
child1.print_list()
    # >> ['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', 'child1_item', ]
child2.print_list()
    # >> ['parent_item1', 'parent_item2', 'child2_item']
```

Comment: Nice. I disagree about `super` not being "simple and clean" though. The `super` method is designed to take the place of explicit references to parent classes by name. That way, if you change the inheritance tree of the current class, `super` automatically resolves any reference issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use metaclass to get updated list as class attribute, i'm not sure if the same thing is able without it.

```
class A(type):                                                
    foo = ['a']
                                                              
    def __new__(self, name, bases, attrs):                         
        if foo := attrs.get('foo'):                                               
            attrs['foo'] = self.foo + foo                       
        return type.__new__(self, name, bases, attrs)                                    
                                                              
                                                              
class B(metaclass=A):                                         
    foo = ['b']      

A.foo 
# >> ['a']
B.foo 
# >> ['a', 'b']
```